# Alternative to INDIRECT() in Excel

Tags: excel

I am currently using a formula **=MATCH(A2,INDIRECT(Q20):INDIRECT(Q22),0)** where A2 contains an item to be searched in a range. The range is dynamic, Q20 holds the start point as **=ADDRESS(Q17,3,4)** and Q22 holds **=ADDRESS(Q18,3,4)**. Q17 and Q18 contain a formula to calculate the desired row number based on user input in a specific cell B2. As you can see, the range is generated dynamically.

**Can anyone suggest doing the same using a non-volatile function ?** This is to be used in multiple places and it slows down the entire spreadsheet if done so. I also want to keep Manual Calculation disabled as I need to return updated results as soon as a the input is entered in the specific cell B2.

Comment: Are the addresses always in column C?

Comment: @user10852207, yes always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INDEX can usually replace INDIRECT and ADDRESS. It is also considered non-volatile (unlike INDIRECT and ADDRESS) so it will not recalculate as much.

```
 =MATCH(A12, INDEX(A:Z, Q17, 3):INDEX(A:Z, Q18, 3), 0)
 'if always in column C then the range can be tightened.
 =MATCH(A12, INDEX(C:C, Q17):INDEX(C:C, Q18), 0)
```

Comment: Bingo, Thanks a lot. Both solutions work, however I prefer the second as I dont want to canvas the whole sheet